# Boot ChromeOS from an Android phones SDCard

Tags: boot, android, google-chrome-os

How can I have my computer boot from an Android phone (ex. Nexus One) into ChomeOS?

Since my Nexus One can act as a Removal Drive, is it possible to create a bootable partition on its SDCard and load a ChromeOS build?

Nightly builds of ChromeOS by Hexxah found here: http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/vanilla.php

Comment: Android and ChomeOS are different things. You'd be better off just installing ChromeOS on your computer or to a flash drive.

Comment: Android smartphone doe not boot from the sd-card at all. The bootloader is always installed on the internal flash system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely possible. I boot a menu with a choice of five different Linux distros directly from my (removable) SD card.

All you have to do is download [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). It is a wizard that lets you add as many OSes you want.

> YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Installer), is the successor to MultibootISOs. It can be used to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive containing multiple operating systems, antivirus utilities, disc cloning, diagnostic tools, and more

[image]

Comment: … and it works with ChromeOS?